# Can an LWC be both a subscriber and publisher using message channels?

Tags: lightning-web-components, publish-subscribe

I have two (A and B)LWCs that do not have a parent child relationship. I am able to send messages from A to B. However, when I try to send the message in reverse after processing the results of the first message, the message does not seem to arrive on the other end.

I am wondering whether LWCs can be both publishers and subscribers.

Component A

```
 subscribeToMessageChannel() {
      
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            RESET_MESSAGE,
            (resetMsg) => this.processResetMessage(resetMsg)
        );
    }
    processResetMessage(resetMsg){
        console.log('received reset message'+ resetMsg.resetMsg);
    }

----
 if(this.deptValue.length > this.numOfDept){ 
                 this.depts = this.deptValue; 
                 this.redDeptArr = this.deptValue;
                 this.searchArray.push(this.deptValue);
                 const payload = { searchString: this.searchArray};
 
                 publish(this.messageContext, SEARCH_MESSAGE, payload);
                 this.numOfDept = this.deptValue.length;
             
             }
```

Component B component

```
 subscribeToMessageChannel() {
      
            this.subscription = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                SEARCH_MESSAGE,
                (message) => this.handleMessage(message)
            );
  
            this.subscription = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                UNCHECKED_MESSAGE,
                (msg) => this.handleUnchecked(msg)
            );
            this.subscription = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                SEARCH_TEXT,
                (mess) => this.handleSearch(mess)
            );
            this.subscription = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                RADIO_MESSAGE,
                (radmsg) => this.handleRadio(radmsg)
            );
    }
----
  let reset = 'reset';
               try{
                const payload = { radioMsg: reset};
                 publish(this.messageContext, RESET_MESSAGE, payload);
                 console.log('published reset');
              }
               catch(error){
            //       console.log('Error in publishing ' + error);
            //   }
```

Anyone who has encountered such a scenario before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a component can be both subscriber and publisher. What's most likely going on is that you have a "race condition", where you're trying to send a message before the other end is ready to receive. To fix this, have each component send the other a message that they will respond to if loaded. This way, if A needs to send a message, it can check if it's already received the initial message from B, and if not, wait until it gets the message, and B can do the same. This will resolve any race conditions that may exist, as they will wait for both sides to be available.

Comment: Thanks. Let me explore that.